# Is it possible to use `mongoimport` to restore data to an AWS DocumentDB through ssh tunnel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel, aws-documentdb

I have an AWS DocumentDB and a bastion server that is located in the same VPC as the DocumentDB.

Here's the command I used to setup an ssh tunnel:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -L 127.0.0.1:27017:my-mongo-db.cluster-cyipmf0aolw0.region.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 myname@bastion.mydomain.com -N
```

And here's the command I used to restore data to the DocumentDB

```
mongoimport --ssl \
    --host="127.0.0.1:27017" \
    --collection=MyCollection \
    --db=MyDatabase \
    --file=MyDatabase.MyCollection.json \
    --numInsertionWorkers 4 \
    --username=myname \
    --password=mypassword \
    --sslCAFile region-bundle.pem
```

The error message I see when running `mongoimport` command is

```
error connecting to host: failed to connect to mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: 127.0.0.1:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs }, ] }
```

I've read the [AWS document here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/backup_restore-dump_restore_import_export_data.html#backup_restore-dump_restore_import_export_data-tutorial). It recommends me to ssh into to the bastion server, then run `mongoimport` inside the bastion server.

Is it possible to run `mongoimport` to restore data through an ssh tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `--tlsInsecure` argument. You're using ssl but connecting to 127.0.0.1 which is not part of the CA.